# Why are boot entries shown by efibootmgr shell different from entries in UEFI boot options?

Tags: boot, uefi, arch-linux

My boot entries, as shown by efibootmgr are the following:

```
Boot0000* rEFInd Boot Manager ...
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager ...
Boot0004* UEFI: SanDisk, Partition 1 ...
```

These same boot entries are shown in /sys/firmware/efi/efivars and when checking via UEFI shell.

However, they are listed differently in the UEFI settings boot priority menu:

```
1. USB Device:UEFI: SanDisk, Partition 1
2. Windows Boot Manager
3. PCIE SSD:Windows Boot Manager (SAMSUNG ...)
4. PCIE SSD
5. Others
6. Others
7. USB CD/DVD
```

Assuming the entries as shown by efibootmgr to be "correct", why do the UEFI settings have more entries? Why are there two entries for Windows? How come rEFInd doesn't have an entry itself? What do entries 5, 6, and 7 represent?

Essentially, I'd assume that what I can see when I mount the EFI partition is what is truly there, so where is this extraneous data coming from? Is this a bug or a feature?

Mobo info per the `Info` section of my UEFI:

```
BIOS Version: GP123
Build Date and Time: 05/13/2022 15:28:13
KBC Version: P004J0
Serial Number: 207QCCV566563
Product Name: 16T90Q-K.AAC7U1
ME FW Version: 16.0.15.1662
PCH Version: A1
```

Comment: What firmware (which motherboard manufacturer) is that? (It looks like it's showing you the "order" numbering, which doesn't have to correspond to the Boot#### numbers which are merely identifiers (the order corresponds to the BootOrder parameter), but still I would have expected it to report even the virtual entries as Boot#### variables as well, like other implementations do.)

Comment: I added mobo info to my question. If any other information is required, I'd be glad to provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Part* of this answer is likely that the firmware's own UI is showing you BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode boot options. These don't normally show up in the output of `efibootmgr` or other tools that query the EFI's boot order because the CSM options are handled a bit differently from the "regular" EFI boot options. I've seen similar things happen on some systems with other hardware-specific boot options, such as network boot options; but these seem to be more commonly handled via the conventional EFI boot order variables, so they usually do show up in both lists.

As to why rEFInd is showing up in the `efibootmgr` output but not in the firmware's own boot manager, I'm afraid I don't know. This sounds like a firmware bug to me, but it's also possible that it's by design. I do not mean that the motherboard's manufacturer is likely to be hiding rEFInd specifically; just that they may be hiding entries that the firmware doesn't recognize or that are formatted in ways that it doesn't support. If rEFInd is launching, then I wouldn't worry too much about this, although you should keep it in mind, since this might complicate certain recovery procedures -- for instance, if Windows resets its boot manager to be the default, you won't be able to rely on the computer's own boot manager and the already-installed version of rEFInd to fix the problem; you'll need to do so from Windows or rely on some other method to fix the problem, like putting rEFInd on a USB flash drive, booting from that and into Linux, and then using `efibootmgr` to adjust the boot order.

If you really want to delve into the mystery of the missing rEFInd boot option, then I'd suggest you try re-installing it in another way. For instance, if you installed rEFInd from Linux, then you could download the latest rEFInd USB image, boot from it, and use its self-install function. This should overwrite your existing rEFInd installation (but keep your existing configuration file) and create a new boot entry. This *might* help because rEFInd's self-install feature uses the EFI's tools to create a boot entry, whereas `efibootmgr` (which rEFInd uses when you install from Linux) uses its own method of creating the entry. The result is that each method creates slightly different NVRAM entries. If the EFI's boot manager is filtering out entries created by `efibootmgr`, then installing rEFInd from itself might work around that issue. Similarly, if you installed rEFInd using its self-install tool, then you could try using `refind-install` in Linux (or create a new entry with an appropriate `efibootmgr` command), or install from Windows (which does things yet a third way).